# place excel or access data into category based on text search

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, tableau-api

very new to VBA/excel/access programming. I've been getting more and more into Tableau, but for what I need right now Tableau is fairly restrictive.

I have a database of retail locations...there are about 42,000 rows of data going back ten years or so. What I'm trying to do is create some code that can do a text search of the store title (say WalMart) and in a blank row assign it to a category like Dept Store, Restaurant, etc.

The problem lies in the store titles...there is no consistency. For example WalMart could be Wal-Mart Wal Mart Walmart Store # 2739 or any other iteration that you can think of.

In Tableau I've been using a command that goes like if Title contains "Wal" and Title contains "Mart" then retailtype="Discount Chain"

This has worked great, but I'm restricted to the number of lines I can include in a calc.

Any help/advice on building something similar in excel or access would be greatly appreciated.

Rich

Answer (score 0):

Sure thing, I can help. Utilize "regular expressions" and `.upper()` and `.lower` string methods to get your job done.

Combine all of the above with the wildcard "*" , and use the `Like` comparison for some results -

```
Dim storetitle as String
Dim match as boolean
storetitle = Cells(1,3).Value

' start a loop here

... match = storetitle Like "*walmart*"  'where match is TRUE or FALSE depending on LIKE
```

utilize a function to create `storetitle.upper(), storetitle.lower()`, etc... and pass these into your test match....

I leave you a reference and urge to ask more questions if you need to.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx

String functions toolkit : 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd789093.aspx
depending on the abstractions / inconsistency in your input data, you may need to get creative and heavy using string functions